# Is it possible to declare a TObjectDictionary that has an array of TStringList as the value?

Tags: arrays, dictionary, object, delphi, dynamic

I have a task where I need to create a specialized editor for a JSON file that contains the following structure:

```json
{
    "intents": [
        {
            "tag": <string_name>,
            "patterns": [
                <string>,
                <string>,
                <string>...
            ],
            "responses": [
                <string>,
                <string>,
                <string>...
            ],
            <repeats arbitrarily]
        }
    ]
}
```

The Form has a drop down and two `TMemo`s. The idea is to use the drop down to edit the `patterns` and `responses` for each `tag`. When done, I save back out to the JSON file.

What I am struggling with is how best to store this data in memory to make it easy to switch from one tag to another. I was thinking a `TObjectDictionary` with the `tag` name as the key and the values as either the `patterns` or `responses` for each one, but then I realized I have to instantiate `x` number of `TObjectDictionary`s dynamically, one for each `tag`.

Is it possible to have a dynamic array with a `string` field and two `TStringList` objects instead? I am using `TJsonTextReader` to walk through the items in the JSON file, and that works fine. I just need some ideas on the best structure to store the data.

Comment: The JSON structure looks to be incorrectly designed. It seems that intents should be a map rather than an array.

Comment: You only need one TObjectDictionary. Use string for keys, and for example a record with two dynamic arrays as the value: type TPatternsAndResponses = record Patterns: array of string; Responses: array of string; end; var IntentsDict: TObjectDictionary<string, TPatternsAndResponses>   This assumes that the ordering of the intents array is not important. (I presume it is is not.)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have no control over the structure of the JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `record` and put whatever you want in it.  Then create an array of record instances. Or store record instances as your dictionary values. Etc.

Comment: I declared the data structure as type

  TIntent = record
    patterns: TStringList;
    responses: TStringList
  end;
...
var
  myDict: TDictionary<string, TIntent>;
  anIntent: TIntent;
...

For each of the tags I instantiate one anIntent and when I am done populating them I add them to the TDictionary with the tag as the key. This seems to work, but now I am struggling to understand how to get the data in and out of the dictionary. I need to copy each stringlist's items to matching tmemo's and viceversa. What is the correct way to reference the stringlists using the key?

Comment: I figured it out after much trial and error...

myDict.TryGetValue(tagSelector.Items[tagSelector.ItemIndex],anIntent)

Comment: Or `myDict['key'].patterns` and `myDict['key'].responses`

Comment: What happens with those statements if they key doesn't exist? Does it throw an exception? TryGetValue does not, which lets me put up a harmless message that the intent could not be found.